# STI wth Strong params undefined local variable or method `attributes'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, ruby-on-rails-6, strong-parameters

undefined local variable or method `attributes' for #CarsController:0x00007fa686991b30

```
  def cars_params(type)
    params.require(type.to_sym).permit(attributes)
  end
```

My model is `CommonCar::RedTrunk`, so type has become `"common_car_red_trunk"`

I am using STI and following this.. https://gist.github.com/danielpuglisi/3c679531672a76cb9a91

I don't really understand why `attributes` was used and why its now failing. I assumed it maybe took the attributes from the required model, but not sure.  Any insights would be helpful to get this working.

Comment: Looking at the gist I guess it is just an example and your need to define the list of attribute names yourself.

Comment: @spickermann, I was thinking that, but # Variant 2 shows different params based on the model.

Comment: I think variant 2 only makes it clear that you can pass different lists of attributes names to both calls. But anyway, `attributes` is undefined and you need to define it or change it to an existing list's name.